# Linq Stored Procedure Issue

Tags: c#, linq

HI all,

I'm having an issue with Linq and my stored procedures. The error I am getting is :

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'. 'Select' not found.

Here is the code found in my DBClasses:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.findahostel_getHostelsByTags")]
public IEnumerable<hostel> findahostel_getHostelsByTags([Parameter(DbType="VarChar(150)")] string tags)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), tags);
    return ((IEnumerable<hostel>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Here is my Linq Code:

```
IQueryable<hostel> hostels = from h in db.findahostel_getHostelsByTags_Name(searchQuery)
                                         select h;
```

I cant find a refrence to an int anywhere.

Matt

Comment: Is the compiler really complaining on that bottom line of code? It sounds unlikely to me. If you hover over the method call, does it show you the return type?

Comment: Hey Jon, I checked as you said and everything was fine; looks like it was a cache issue with my host referencing the old file. All sorted now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to cast result.ReturnValue as an `IEnumerable<hostel>` and I'm pretty sure that ReturnValue is an int.  It is what the stored procedure returns, which is not to be confused with the rows that a stored proc also "returns"

Comment: Yep that would be correct mate; ended up being a cache issue on my hoste end.